# Not able to send email with HTML template (S-Docs)

Tags: trigger, send-email, document

My following code is working for generate the s-doc as expected but it is not sending email with HTML template.

```
Id sDocTemplateId = [Select Id from SDOC__SDTemplate__c where Name = 'PDF template' Limit 1].Id;
Id sDocTemplateId1 = [Select Id from SDOC__SDTemplate__c where Name = 'HTML template' Limit 1].Id;

SDOC.SDBatch.CreateSDoc(UserInfo.getSessionId(), UserInfo.getUserName(), 'id='+c.id+'&Object=Case&doclist='+sDocTemplateId1+','+sDocTemplateId+'&sendEmail=1&oneclick=false');
```

if i remove HTML template from the URL then it working fine but when i try to add HTML template to get body in email then it's not working.

I am posting here because might be some folks worked on s-doc